# Merge two eloquent collections into one object property?

Tags: php, laravel-5, stdclass, object-properties

We can create empty objects in php using th `stdClass` and we can add properties to it like this:

```
$data = new stdClass;

$data->xyz = something;
```

But how could we add more things to a property? i mean something like this:

```
$data->xyz += somethingElse;
```

Is that possible?

What i want to do is this: i have to get some data from a database and i would like to store records of two tables in one property. To get data from a table and store it in a property i do this:

```
    $data = new stdClass;

    $data->gallery = \DB::table('RestaurantMenuOptions')
        ->select('Name', 'Image')
        ->get();

    $data->gallery2 = \DB::table('Promotions')
        ->select('Name', 'Image')
        ->get();
```

What i would like is to store them all in a single `gallery` property. By the way i use Laravel 5.

**Edit 1**

What i want is to join the data called from the table *`'RestaurantMenuOptions'`* and *`'Promotions'`* into one property of `$data`. I'm guessing if its possible to join two variables or if it's possible to get data from two unrelated tables using Eloquent?

What i've thought so far is to [convert the models to array](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json) and then join them, but how do i convert the joined arrays to a model so that it in the views?

**Edit 2**

I found that it's possible to merge eloquent collections, but if the tables has the same type of PK and there are repeated records with same PK, they'll be overridden, so i decided to convert the collections to arrays merge them and access to them like them like this:

```
{{ $item['key'] }}
```

If someone has a better way to do it i'll apreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

I think that a better way would be doing a for loop instead to make it somewhat more dynamic.

Code:

```php
class Data {
    private $property, $property2;

    public function  __construct($property,$property2) {
        $this->Property = $property;
        $this->Property2 = $property2;
    }
}

$dataArray = array();

$dataArray[] = new Data('Name',Image);
$dataArray[] = new Data('Name',Image);

print "<pre>";
print_r($dataArray);
print "</pre>";

for ($i=0; $i < count($dataArray); $i++) { 
    // do something with the array of objects
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment... if you can do an example of it then this would be an answer

Comment: Updated it with some code so you can see what i mean. Please remove the downvote if you find the answer helpful

Comment: Hmmm, i understand what you mean, but your answer means to me a lot of code for the purpose, maybe if it would be possible to join two variables into one and then assign them to a property, that would be better...

Comment: Im not quite sure if i am following you. This is a proper way of making an array of objects for later use. I do not know if i would do it in another way than this, it gives you good control of the objects as they are added to the array. But if you want to join two variables and assign them to a property you could simply do: `$data->xyz = $data->xyz + somethingElse;` But i dont know exactly what you are after so i may have missunderstood your goal.

Comment: I already tried that, but it gives an error, Laravel treats it as a Collection, and the error says that it cant convert Collection to int